# Does NUnit provide a multiple enumeration helper?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, ienumerable, enumeration

In my company code base we have a bunch of extension method for `IEnumerable` object.

Some of this method enumerate multiple time the parameter given in entry.

Of course, we don't want the so I'm going to fix those methods.

But first I would like to write some unit test to detect the multiple enumeration.

I come to an implementation of `IEnumerable` that provide enumeration count information :

```
public class TestableEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    readonly T[] values;

    public TestableEnumerable(T[] values)
    {
        this.values = values;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        EnumerationCount++;
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            yield return value;
        }
    }

    public int EnumerationCount { get; private set; }
}
```

The test look like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class EnumerableExtensionsTests
{
    TestableEnumerable<int> sut;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        sut = new TestableEnumerable<int>(new[] { -10, 0, 10 });
    }

    [Test]
    public void Append_Enumerate_Once()
    {
        var result = sut.Append(1).ToArray();
        Assert.That(sut.EnumerationCount, Is.EqualTo(1));
    }
}
```

Does NUnit provide any mechanism to accomplish this more lightly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looks only for `GetEnumerator` method calls count, you can use any mock framework to create fake enumerable. [There is NUnit.Mock framework. But now it's no longer being developed and NUnit project uses NSubstitute](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit.Mocks/).

```
var fakeEnumerable = Substitute.For<IEnumerable<int>>();
fakeEnumerable.GetEnumerator().Returns(Substitute.For<IEnumerator<int>>());

fakeEnumerable.ToArray();
fakeEnumerable.ToArray();

fakeEnumerable.Received(2).GetEnumerator();
```

Also there is another way to enumerate collection twice.   It can be done by using `IEnumerator.Reset` metod.
So it may worth to check `Reset` method calls too.